# Sql case statement does not return all value when the variable is empty

Tags: mysql, sql

May I know is there anyway to return all the value in database when the variable is empty and return specific value when the variable has value?

I try to return all the restaurant with both halal and non halal when the variable is empty, and retutn specific value when the variable has value. My code look like

```
$halal="Halal";
$category=" ";

    $sql = "SELECT Restaurant.*, Images.thumbnail_url 
     from Restaurant 
     LEFT JOIN Images ON Images.id = 
     (select id from Images
     where Images.image_id = Restaurant.id
     limit 1)
     where MATCH (RestaurantName,RestaurantLocation)      AGAINST('$search_query') and  ( RestaurantHalal = CASE WHEN '$halal' IS NULL   THEN RestaurantHalal  ELSE '$halal' END)
     and Restaurant.is_active = 1";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my careless, just add in another or to empty set will solve the whole issue.

```
 $halal="";
 $category=" ";

$sql = "SELECT Restaurant.*, Images.thumbnail_url 
 from Restaurant 
 LEFT JOIN Images ON Images.id = 
 (select id from Images
 where Images.image_id = Restaurant.id
 limit 1)
 where MATCH (RestaurantName,RestaurantLocation) AGAINST('$search_query') and  ( RestaurantHalal = CASE WHEN '$halal' IS NULL OR '$halal' = ' ' THEN RestaurantHalal  ELSE '$halal' END)
 and Restaurant.is_active = 1";
```